# 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Cache' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, .net-assembly

**Error 24  The type 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Cache' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching, Version=5.0.414.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35**

i have following error when build our project.
i have implement some additional functionaly in our own cache class that is inherited from Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Caching.Cache.when i uesd this ddl in another project then 
they give following error ..please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try to use the actual public key the assemblies were signed with.

Also check this [Referencing Enterprise Library Assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650106.aspx)

Comment: i do'nt know where i check actual public key the assemblies ....i check your refernce but same error occured.if you have any other solution pls share...Thanks

Comment: @user2826455:- Use the following command,

**sn –T myDLL.dll**

This will give you the public key token. Remember one thing this only works if the assembly has to be strongly signed.